# Print HTML comment when passed through conditional statement

Tags: template-toolkit

I'm new to Template Toolkit, trying to update some existing templates, so I appreciate any help received.

I've setup a conditional statement that checks for the name of a module and then outputs that name as a dirified HTML ID (e.g. "This is a Title" -> "this_is_a_title").

Code: `<div [% IF Tag.module_name %]id="[% Tag.module_name | dirify %]"[% END %]>`

In some cases, however, a title entered has been wrapped in an HTML comment. That's outside of my control, so what I'd like to do is work around that somehow. I'd like to either:

- strip the comment tags, leaving the comment text itself so that it can still be used for the ID; or
- ignore the titles that use HTML comments and not insert the ID attribute at all

Currently, the output for titles with HTML comments ends up as `<div id="">`, which is ugly. I've tried locating the code I need, and done multiple searches for a solution, but I can't seem to work it out. Will this be possible or will I need to accept the empty ID?

UPDATE: passing an additional filter for HTML, before the dirify filter, ended up working to remove the HTML comments and dirifying the remaining text. Using [% ATTag.list_name | html | dirify %] helped to output a title formatted as `<!--This is a Title-->` to `this_is_a_title`. I was also able to reduce my original code example above to simply `<div id="[% Tag.module_name | html | dirify %]">` which outputs `<div id="this_is_a_title">` (or whatever the dirified title ends up being).

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you need:

```
[%- SET dirified = Tag.module_name FILTER dirify;
    IF dirified; -%]
    <div id="[% dirified %]">
[%- ELSE -%]
    <div>
[%- END-%]
```

Without a concrete example of the problem with HTML comments it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks, @RET. That code didn't work for me, but it led me to try a few different things I wasn't previously aware of. In the end, it turned out passing the HTML filter before the Dirify filter worked for my needs. e.g. `[% ATTag.list_name | html | dirify %]`.